# jsPlumb function failed : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resetBounds')

Tags: angular, jsplumb

When i add connector property with type 'Bezier', then upon adding connection it throws

```
jsPlumb function failed : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resetBounds')
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'canvas')
at BrowserJsPlumbInstance.setConnectorHover (jsplumb.browser-ui.es.js:4774)
```

I'm adding the following property to addEndPoint

```
import {BezierConnector} from '@jsplumb/connector-bezier'
{
    endpoint: {
      type: DotEndpoint.type,
      options:{
        radius: 7
    }
    },
    paintStyle: { fill: '#99cb3a' },
    source: true,
    connector:{
      type:BezierConnector.type,
      options:{
        curviness:50
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of people coming across this in the future, the issue was discussed [on Github](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/1064), and the cause looks to be mixed versions of jsPlumb packages.

You have to use the same version of `@jsplumb/connector-flowchart` as `@jsplumb/browser-ui`, etc. Theoretically this is enforced by the packages themselves; it is unclear in this case how the mismatch came about.